# Available command for get coordinates from desktop, dash to dock and top bar buttons and icons

Tags: bash, gnome, icons, automation

I have a doubt about if there is any command available to get x,y coordinates from positions where desktop icons are located, as well as dash to dock icons and buttons like Activities, navigators, date/time, wifi, sound and so on at the top bar?

The only one that I found is `gio info` one but it didn't give me the coordinates from the icons and I have used `xdotool` also but it doesn't gave me the exactly position of each icon/button visible on the desktop, and go for image processing I don't know if it is an efficient way or it would be "kill fly with a cannon shot".

Comment: If you are running an X Desktop Environment you can run `xdotool getmouselocation` in a terminal window to show you where your mouse is located by coordinate even if you are hovering over an icon.

Comment: I already used ```xdotool``` @Terrance thanks for the tip, but my aim is map the buttons and icons available and get the exactly position of each of them to doesn't look like that I am doing a blinding automation clicking on them

Comment: So what exact coordinates are you looking for?  The upper most left tip of each icon?  The exact middle of each icon?  Icons can cover like 50x50 pixels.